# Javascript count-down , error in the "HOUR" format

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I am unable to make hour convert in 2digits . The present output will include the whole hour , it isnt excluding the days. You'll get a better idea of it if you run it. Try `timer(7.543e+7);` in the console.

```
let countdown;
const timerDisplay=document.querySelector('.time_left');
function timer(seconds){
const now= Date.now();
const then=now+seconds*1000;
displayTimeLeft(seconds);

countdown= setInterval(()=>{
    const secondsLeft= Math.round((then-Date.now())/1000);
    if(secondsLeft<0){
        clearInterval(countdown);
        return;
    }
    displayTimeLeft(secondsLeft);
},1000);
}   
function displayTimeLeft(seconds){
    const days=Math.floor(seconds/(24*60*60));
    const hours=Math.floor(seconds/3600);
    const minutes=Math.floor((seconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    const remainderSeconds=seconds%60;
  const display = `${days}:${hours}:${minutes}:${remainderSeconds < 10 ? '0' : '' }${remainderSeconds}`;
    document.title= display;
    timerDisplay.textContent= display;
}
```

output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOfgP.png)

The output should instead be `[873:22:27:53]` .

]

Comment: Are you not just looking for `const hours=Math.floor(seconds/3600) - 24 * days;` ?

Comment: I did try that earlier , didnt work.

Comment: const hours=Math.floor(seconds/3600 - days*24);
    const minutes=Math.floor(seconds/60 - hours*60 - days*24*60);

Comment: Didnt work either.

Comment: Post a working snippet.

Comment: In the question editor there is a button that will open the snippet editor where you can place your html, css and script to produce a functioning example of your problem. We can then fully understand the issue. Have a go.